# RefineryCMS for RESTful API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, content-management-system

I need to build a site with a CMS interface and RESTful api (to use with a clientside framework, angularJS). Would RefineryCMS work for me?

Also, does anyone have experience with Refinery, LocomotiveCMS, or any other rails-based CMSs? Do you prefer one over the other? Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by CMS interface?  Like you need to allow users to create Pages, embed images/files, etc?

I use Refinery alot, and really like it.  However, it has no built in support for a RESTful api like you want, I'm assuming you mean via JSON or something.  To do this you'd have to override the refinerycms-core engine and it's crud.rb file.  This is where Refinery defines all the REST actions dynamically.  I'm sure you'd have to also override other engines depending on which functionality of the core engines you're using.  I'd probably try doing a proof of concept first, then on seeing how smoothly that goes, decide to continue or try another CMS framework.

Another lightweight alternative to Refinery is [Comfortable Mexican Sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa).  It was pretty easy to add on to a full Rails app I maintain to provide CMS functionality.  Though I didn't have to override any internal parts of it.  I've never used LocomotiveCMS. You could also role your own CMS and use something like ActiveAdmin for the backend.

Comment: Thanks Supalrish. I decided to use Locomotive CMS, which gives me both the CMS interface for my client as well as a RESTful API that I can use to build an Angular frontend. So far it's working great and I'd recommend it to others.